# jqueryui button with raphael icon: where do the extra (padding?) pixels come from?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, raphael

I'm trying to use `raphaeljs` to create `svg` icons on `jqueryui` buttons. I've succeeded in removing a lot of the padding that `jqueryui` is adding, but there is an additional 5 pixel border below the `Raphael paper` that I can't seem to figure out. I'm using Chrome's dev tools to identify problems, which helped me figure out that a `<span>` was being added with padding that I had to remove. But I'm stuck on where the 5 pixels below the `div` are coming from...

Three questions:
1) What is the source of these extra pixels?
2) How do I get rid of it?
3) How can I figure this out in the future without relying on the excellent people of `StackOverflow`?

Code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7VtF/)):  (Attempt is to create a button with only a `Raphael` paper (20x20 px) as the content.)
HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="button">
    <label for="button">
        <div id="labeldiv"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#button').button();
var paper=Raphael('labeldiv',20,20);
paper.circle(10,10,10);
$('#labeldiv').parent().css('padding','0px');
```

(follow the above link for the result with the extra 5 pixels below the `paper`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the `line-height:normal` being applied to the `svg` container `div#labeldiv`.
Try setting it to `line-height:1em` or lesser if necessary

Comment: Excellent! This works, which answers most of the question. Unless a better-documented answer comes along I will accept this one soon. The remaining piece is this: how should I have figured this out, so in the future I know where to be looking for similar issues? I've been using Chrome dev tools to look at computed styles etc but didn't see this information anywhere...

Comment: @tmpearce I have a thumb rule: *`Children elements' size`, `height`, `padding`, `margin`- if none of these work than more often than not its the `line-height` that's causing the issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Fix the height of labeldiv :

```
$('#labeldiv').css('height','20px');
```